# How can i make the AI dumber? and why doesnt my score system work? (PING PONG!) NEED HELP

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Pong
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //variables
        float ballX = 255,
        ballY = new Random().Next(1, 280),
        ballSpeed = 3.0f,
        paddleHeight = 80,
        cpuHeight = 80,
        cpuSkill = 2.0f;
        int hits = 0;
        Timer t = new Timer();
        bool directionX = true,
        directionY = true,
        ingame = false;
        int player1score = 0, player2score = 0;
        SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        String beginString = "Welcome to Pong! \n" + "by Javier!";

        public Form1()
        {
            //Initializes the component
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void normalToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            menuStrip1.Visible = false;
            ingame = true;
            t = new Timer();
            hits = 0;
            ballX = 255;
            ballY = new Random().Next(1, 280);
            ballSpeed = 3.0f;
            directionY = true;
            directionX = true;

            //Sets up timer
            t.Interval = 5;
            t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
            t.Start();

            //shows picture
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);

            //Creates mouse movement
            this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseMove);
        }

        private void destroyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void battleToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void easyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            easyToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
            mediumToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
            hardToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
            pongmasterToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
            cpuSkill = 0.0f;
        }

        private void mediumToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            easyToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
            mediumToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
            hardToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
            pongmasterToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
            cpuSkill = 2.5f;
        }

        private void hardToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            easyToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
            mediumToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
            hardToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
            pongmasterToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
            cpuSkill = 5.5f;
        }

        private void pongmasterToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            easyToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
            mediumToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
            hardToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
            pongmasterToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
            cpuSkill = 6.5f;
        }

        void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //Moves the paddle to the mouse's y-coordinate
            paddleHeight = e.Y - 40;
        }

        void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Causes ball to bounce of windows
            if (ballX + 10 >= 439)
            {
                //directionX = false;

            }
            if (ballX - 10 <= 1)
                directionX = true;
            if (ballY + 10 >= 263)
                directionY = false;
            if (ballY - 10 <= 1)
                directionY = true;

            //movement of ball
            if (directionX == true)
                ballX += ballSpeed;
            if (directionY == true)
                ballY += ballSpeed;
            if (directionX == false)
                ballX -= ballSpeed;
            if (directionY == false)
                ballY -= ballSpeed;

            //AI Vs player
            if (directionY == true && ballX >= 225 && cpuHeight + 40 < ballY)
                cpuHeight += cpuSkill;
            if (directionY == false && ballX >= 225 && cpuHeight + 40 > ballY)
                cpuHeight -= cpuSkill;

            // Player vs paddle
            if (directionX == false && ballY + 10 > paddleHeight && ballY - 10 < paddleHeight + 80 && ballX <= 20)
            {
                directionX = true;
                hits += 1;




            }
            if (directionX == true && ballY + 10 > cpuHeight && ballY - 10 < cpuHeight + 80 && ballX >= 421)
            {
                directionX = false;
                hits += 1;
            }

            if (((ballX - 10) <= 1) || ((ballX + 20) >= 450))                 
            {
                if( (ballX - 10)<=1)
                    ++player2score;
                if((ballX + 20) >= 450)
                    ++player1score;

            }



            Invalidate();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);
            SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Orange);
            SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            if (ingame == true)
            {
                p.Width = 2;
                g.DrawEllipse(p, ballX - 10, ballY - 10, 20, 20);
                g.FillEllipse(b, ballX - 10, ballY - 10, 20, 20);
                g.DrawRectangle(p, 5, paddleHeight, 6, 80);
                g.DrawRectangle(p, 431, cpuHeight, 6, 80);
                b.Color = Color.Blue;
                g.FillRectangle(b, 431, cpuHeight, 6, 80);
                g.FillRectangle(b, 5, paddleHeight, 6, 80);
                g.DrawString(string.Format("{0} : {1}",player1score, player2score), new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 14),drawBrush,215, 10);


            }
            if (ingame == false)
                g.DrawString(beginString, new Font(Font.FontFamily, 16), new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), new Point(140, 140), StringFormat.GenericDefault);














        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your AI starting to feel emotion now? CAN THIS PROGRAM FEEL LOVE?! Also, it'd be nice if you could include your question and further details of your question within the post!

Comment: You're supposed to show some effort on your part before posting a question. For instance, the empty function definitions (and blank lines at that), do not help at all. You have to explain how you expect your scoring to work, and how it is failing to meet your expectations. What is the AI supposed to do and how is it not doing it? (The code only mentions AI in a comment that explains nothing about it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that AI, I would suggest creating a random number to make the AI's paddle vary rather than being +-2. The AI's paddle is currently still "aligned" to the ball, its just offset by a number. Not really an AI when you are cloning the coordinates.

For the scoring system, make sure you added up the dimensions properly. It is very hard to make sense of all the different pixels plastered in the code. How big is the actual playing area?